# What is equivalence of $(p \vee q) \wedge \neg (p \vee q)$?

Tags: logic

My simple question is what is  equivalence of

$$(p \vee q) \wedge  \neg (p \vee q)?$$

EDIT: I'm new to symbolic  logic, I don't understand why I got downvote here. It's not shame asking simple questions.

Comment: Let $a = p \vee q$. Then you have $a \wedge ¬ a$.

Comment: Is it that simple?

Comment: @kenn : Yes it is.

Comment: Then it is equal to 0?

Comment: There are infinitely many statements equivalent to $(p \lor q) \wedge  \neg (p \vee q)$

Comment: Are you sure that the problem ask **exactly** : "what is equivalence of ..." ?? Is the exercise about what : truth-tables, De Morgan' laws ... ?

Comment: what do you mean by "what is equivalence of"? Do you mean "simplify" for example?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA
Yes, it's a problem from test booklet of my nephew. After the question, it lists choices like A) q B) p C) 0 ...

Comment: This formula is always false, so the appropriate answer is C. You weren't downvoted because the question is easy but because it's unclear: "what is equivalence of" is not a phrase with a well-defined meaning. Listing the answer choices in the question would help; more generally it's a good idea to include the context in which you came across a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula

> $(p \lor q) \land \lnot (p \lor q)$

cannot be equivalent to $p$ nor $q$ because - as said by @Chris Taylor yesterday - it is equivalent to $r \land \lnot r$, i.e. is a formula that is always false, while $p$ and $q$ are propositional letters that can have (according to the "situation", i.e. interpretation) sometimes the value true and sometimes the value false.

So, strictly speaking, the formula is equivalent to *FALSE* (symbiolized as $\bot$) but you can use a formula identically false whatever, like $p \land \lnot p$ itself.